# spring framework 3.2.9 annotations

Tags: spring

i try to use spring framework 3.2.9
that's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>3_2_9</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>3_2_9</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>3_2_9</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and i have 3 classes
*hello/MessageService.java:

```
package hello;

public interface MessageService {
    String getMessage();
}
```

*hello/MessagePrinter.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessagePrinter {

    final private MessageService service;

    @Autowired
    public MessagePrinter(MessageService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(this.service.getMessage());
    }
}
```

*hello/Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Bean
    MessageService mockMessageService() {
        return new MessageService() {
            public String getMessage() {
              return "Hello World!";
            }
        };
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
          new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
      MessagePrinter printer = context.getBean(MessagePrinter.class);
      printer.printMessage();
  }
}
```

but the import cannot be resolved and the annotations that i have used are no known.any one can help me..

Comment: Your code and dependencies settings seem correct. How do you compile your source code? (using mvn command?)

Answer (score 0):

The `@Autowired` annotation resides in the `spring-beans` project, try adding the following dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```